# Private whois: How to know the owner?

Tags: domain, privacy, domain-name, privacy-protection, whois

Is there a way to get information about the owner of a domain with private whois ?

Answer (score 5):

Other than by court order, I would hope not.

Otherwise it's not very private.

Answer (score 4):

You could send email to an administrative address at the domain.  GoDaddy's private domain service simply forwards that stuff on to the domain owner, and I suspect that is the usual behavior.  If you get a reply, then you know.